# Visualization in pyqtgraph for node network?

Tags: pyqt5, networkx, pyqtgraph, cytoscape

I have a collection of network points stored as Nodes and Edges for use in networkx, but would like to impliment a more advanced visualzation tool into the pyqtgraph widget so that I can use it in a GUI designed in pyqt5.

The problem with utilizing matplotlib to visualize the nx network is that the colors are not displayed, gravity cannot be manipulated, ect...

Figure 1

[image]

The optimal case would be if cytoscape or Gephi had a backend to allow for integration into these sorts of GUIs, since I am able to get things spaced out for visualization very well with these after constructing the network in nx.

[image: Figure 2]

Both figures were of the same data, the only difference is that figure 2 was visualized using Gephi, allowing for the nodes to be repelled a little more, making them readable.

Is there a way to:

1. Adjust repulsion in networkx when NOT manually dictating node placement?
2. Visualize a network in a pyqtGraph widget? (preferably interactive)

Comment: Have you explored pyqtgraph's GraphItem? `A GraphItem displays graph information as a set of nodes connected by lines (as in ‘graph theory’, not ‘graphics’). Useful for drawing networks, trees, etc.`